# Copying file through python

Tags: python, buffer, file-copying

I'm copying a single large archive file through python by reading and writing source and destination file (in byte mode)through OPEN function because I need to display a progress bar.

Now how much buffer should I read and write in each loop so that copy is fast enough and doesn't feel slow compared to copying through OS. Is there any way to calculate this optimum buffer amount keeping in mind network speed or any other factor?

Comment: "Now how much buffer should I read and write in each loop so that copy is fast enough and doesn't feel slow compared to copying through OS". The operating system is always involved in I/O operations. Frankly, Python is a user-process that relies on system calls. Therefore, when you issue a `read` call, Python needs to use a syscall to pass the request on to the kernel. As such, Python can't be faster when copying files, this is invalid.

Comment: No you got me wrong! I do not want it to be faster than OS. At first in f.read() function I passed 8*1024 of bytes to read. But it took too much of time to copy. Does buffer amount affects copying speed.

Comment: @user8349741 The buffer  of a file is just in-memory data to be sent to disk when the buffer exceeds N number of bytes. In top of your OS's buffers, Python has buffers too. Copying a file involves reading the data from the disk or the storage device. The reading speed could be slow for various factors, like when your partitions are not properly aligned in a hard drive for example. Also if the kernel is busy doing a lot of I/O operations, this hinders performance as well.

Comment: For file operations use [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#module-shutil) module it has a plethora of tools for that.

Comment: But I need to copy a single large file maybe around 13-15 gb. Is there any function in shutil which returns how much data has been copied so that I can use that return value to update my progress bar.

Comment: If 8*1024 takes so much to copy, that's a limitation in your system I believe. Unfortunately, `shutil` doesn't provide that.